# Extrude by unit amount, not percentage

Tags: extrude, units, measurement

I've got a simple square plane (Blender 2.83) that is 66 x 66 meters and that I created by first adding a plane, then setting its X and Y dimensions in the <kbd>n</kbd> menu ("Item" tab in Object Mode) and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> in the end to "(Apply) Scale", so it afterwards also displays the right "edge length" in Edit Mode.

Now I want to extrude the corners to add a small border and make the plane 70 x 70 meters.

If I press <kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>, the plane grows to twice its original size. To grow it to roughly 70m, I have to calculate the percentage (`70 / (66/100) = about 106`), then extrude with <kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>1.06</kbd>, which is of course still a tiny bit off.

How do I extrude with the actual measurement I want to add, instead of the percentage, e.g.: make <kbd>e</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> add a small border to turn a 10x10 plane into a 14x14 plane (hence, add 2 units on each side)? Is there another way to do this without using extrusion, while still easily and quickly creating new vertices on the outside?

Edit: You can find a screenshot what I want to do (but with units, not percentages) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KR10.png). Please don't mind the glitchy look, I didn't clean up the double faces.

Comment: i'm not really sure about your setup and your endgoal. how does the border you'd like to add look like? Could you show an image of what you have and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Quick tip: turn on snapping (shift + tab) and use the mouse to scale to whole units.

Comment: Basically think of a room: The overall length/width is 70 units (Blender is set to metric) and the wall is 2 units thick, which means that the inside of the room is 66x66 units, which is also my starting point. I use the extrude function to keep the 4 original corner vertices (which turn into the inside corners) and add 4 new ones (= outside corner vertices). This way I can easily extrude the the "border" (= the outside "ring") up (e + z) to create the actual walls.

Comment: Don't use extrude + scale, but extrude along normals alt+E.

Comment: Is that the same as e.g. e+z because that's not what I want. I want to create an outside ring on the same z level.

Comment: Well, try it... Use "offset even" option once done...

Comment: you could easily do it the other way round. Scale your plane to fit the outside edges and use inset (i) to scale the inside to your liking. Insetting uses blender units instead of persentages.

Comment: I did, alt+e only extrudes along the z axis.

Comment: You can find a screenshot what I want to do (but with units, not percentages) [here](https://i.imgur.com/cBOjPwu.png).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inset` for this.

Start with the outer dimensions of your plane.
Mine is 7 x 7

[image]

Press <kbd>i</kbd> and type in the offset you need (in my case its 1 unit, so I end up with a inner square of 6x6 units.

[image]

Make sure Offset Even is checked in the bottom left corner.

Comment: Inset is a bit buggy for me and only works half of the time but when it does, it does as shown in your images. Unfortunately you have to know at the very beginning how big you want your walls to be, so you can add that to the measurements of the floor, which I don't in my main project (at least not yet). Is there a way to make the inset work as an "outset"? I tried using a negative value but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Extrude along normals <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> and choose *"along normal"*:

[image]

Once validated, you can use the operator panel to set the exact size you want. Also check *"offset even"*.

Or, starting from a plane, choose inset <kbd>I</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: That's what I did but it only extrudes up/down.

Comment: The extrude along normals doesn't work like this on a plane.

Comment: @bstnhnsl, sure but initially though he used a cube... as extruding make no sense is case of plane.

Comment: You're in "Modeling" mode, right? When I switch to "vertex select" with "1" (in edit mode), select everything with "a", then press "i", I get the same dashed line as you are but there's neither a menu nor does it actually do anything. Plus, I want to place the new vertices on the outside, not the inside.

Comment: I see, I have to type something to make the inset appear and the popup only shows up after I finish with enter. I tried, it won't let me use negative values though, which is no surprise for something called "INset".

Comment: Could either start with the larger plane and inset. Or extrude and scale, then after that inset "out" with I then O keys (O during inset) then remove the larger part. As there is "outset" from boundaries afaik

Comment: I've been using e+s so far but it's a pain in the butt to have to do the math for every small bit and I can only use the "inset" function if I know right from the beginning how wide the outside has to be. I tried i + o but then it creates a glitchy part that also won't grow past half the width. "Inset" might also be slightly bugged for me because half of the time moving the mouse does nothing and the extra vertices don't show up, even after entering a number and pressing enter.

Comment: What is the overall context exactly? As from what I know so far, we are just talking about moving 4 vertices. So how complex is the situation globally?

Comment: The current test object is just the plane that I want to add a wall to to basically create an open box (going to extrude the bottom down afterwards), so it's not just about moving vertices but creating new ones to add a border to the floor that I can then e+z. My actual non-test object is a more complex room that also needs walls but I don't know yet how thick I want to make them. e+x/y/z all work with units, not percentages (as shown by "edge length"), so it's weird that e+s would work in a completely different way and there's no way to change it (is there?).